# How to setup Tinymce init config using external file

Tags: tinymce

i want to use multiple editor .there one global TinyMce init config will be defined. I want to override this basic setup in every editor based on requirement.

Answer (score 0):

So you need one, global TinyMCE config, and then override the global config if needed in each additional editor based on what you need?

If that's the case, one way to do this is to set up a common config variable with the global, TinyMCE init config. Then you can do one of the following with it:

1. Just use the common config as your editor instance.
2. you could extend the common config with more js.
3. Ignore the commonconfig and create a new editor as needed (essentially overwriting it).

The common config:

```
//filename: script.js

let commonConfig = {
    plugins: "advcode advtable autocorrect autolink checklist codesample editimage emoticons image link linkchecker lists media mediaembed powerpaste table tinymcespellchecker",
    menubar: false,
    inline: true,
    toolbar_persist: true,
    object_resizing: false,
    mobile: {
        toolbar_mode: 'floating'
    },
    spellchecker_language: 'en',
    spellchecker_active: true
}
```

And the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>TinyMCE Common Config</title>
        <script src="commonEditor.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.tiny.cloud/1/no-api-key/tinymce/6/tinymce.min.js" referrerpolicy="origin"></script>
        <script>
            tinymce.init({
                selector: "#editor-description-content",
                toolbar: "blocks | bold italic forecolor backcolor | numlist bullist checklist | link image emoticons table codesample hr blockquote | code ",
                fixed_toolbar_container: '#editor-description-toolbar',
                placeholder: "Add a description",

                setup: (editor) => {

                    editor.on('focus', () => {
                        document.getElementById('editor-description-wrap').classList.add('enabled');
                    });
                  },
                  ...commonConfig
            });

            //Script without common config
            tinymce.init({
                selector: "#editor",
                plugins: "autocorrect powerpaste tinymcespellchecker",
                menubar: true
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Textarea 1 with common config</h2>
        <div name="" id="editor-description-content" cols="30" rows="10">A tinyMCE editor with a common config</div>
        <h2>Textarea 2 without common config</h2>
        <textarea name="" id="editor" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    </body>
</html>
```